# angular output variable to parent from nth child two

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

i need to input and output variable to/from two childs

**My parent 
*deposit.component.html***

```
<div>
    <app-new-or-update-deposit [(isOpenedModal)]="isOpenedModal"></app-new-or-update-deposit>
</div>
```

**deposit.component.ts**

```
...
export class DepositsComponent implements OnInit {

  public isOpenedModal = false;

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {}

  openModal() {
    this.isOpenedModal = true;
  }
}
```

**My first child 
*new-or-update-deposit.component.html***

```
<app-modal [(isOpenedModal)]="isOpenedModal">
    <div body>
        Body content
    </div>
    <div footer>
        Footer content
    </div>
</app-modal>
```

**new-or-update-deposit.component.ts**

```
...
export class NewOrUpdateDepositComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() isOpenedModal: boolean;
  @Output() isOpenedModalChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

**My two child
*modal.component.html***

```
<div class="modal fade" [ngClass]="isOpenedModal ? 'show modal-block' : ''" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" (click)="close()">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-backdrop fade show" *ngIf="isOpenedModal"></div>
```

**modal.component.ts**

```
...
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() isOpenedModal: boolean;
  @Output() isOpenedModalChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() { }

  close() {
    this.isOpenedModalChange.emit(false)
  }
}
```

[image: check image]

**OK i solvet it with**
**In *new-or-update-deposit.component.html***

```
<app-modal [(isOpenedModal)]="isOpenedModal" (isOpenedModalChange)="onIsOpenedModalChange($event)">
    <div body>
        Body content
    </div>
    <div footer>
        Footer content
    </div>
</app-modal>
```

becouse **isOpenedModalChange** is event i can call function

**In *new-or-update-deposit.component.ts***

```
...
export class NewOrUpdateDepositComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() isOpenedModal: boolean;
  @Output() isOpenedModalChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() { }

  onIsOpenedModalChange(value) {
    this.isOpenedModalChange.emit(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't add tags to your questions that aren't relevant. Your question is about `angular`, not `angularjs`.

Comment: You could instead provide a service at the deposit component level, then inject this into the children. The modal component just needs to subscribe to an observable on this service which will open it when the click event is raised on the service. Likewise, you can raise an event on this service when the modal is closed and anything interested in this event can subscribe to it. Here is an example of this approach https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-service?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Rxjs subject is useful to you here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bubble your own events as far as you wish by handling and emitting events on each component that the event passes through.

**parent.html**

```
<app-child (myevent)="onMyEvent($event)">
</app-child>
```

**child.ts**

```
@Output() myEvent: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

onMyEvent(e: number): void {
  this.myEvent.emit(e);
}
```

**child.html**

```
<app-grand-child (myevent)="onMyEvent($event)>
</app-grand-child>
```

etc etc